# Parallel for loop with specific number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading

What is the best way, how to implement parallel for loop with a specified number of threads?
Like this:

```
int maxThreads=5;
int curretnThreads=0;

for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){

   if(currentThreads<maxThreads){

      start thread...... 

   }else{
        wait...
   }

}
```

Comment: "*What is the best way*" define "best".

Comment: @Pshemo best way= use `runnable`, `thread` class, or how?

Comment: I would say the best way is to use the Java 8 `Stream` API. The second best way is to use [`ExecutorService.fixedThreadPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html). The absolute worst way is to use raw `Thread`s.

Answer (score 2):

I would first create a `ForkJoinPool` with a fixed number of threads:

```
final ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(numThreads);
```

Now simply execute a parallel stream operation in a task:

```
forkJoinPool.submit(() -> {
    IntStream.range(0, 10_000)
            .parallel()
            .forEach(i -> {
                //do stuff
            });
});
```

Obviously this example simply translates your code literally. I would recommend that you use the `Stream` API to its fullest rather than just loop `[0, 10,000)`.